# Remove white space between strings in Python

Tags: python, loops, strip, lowercase

I am doing some practice code exercises, and the question is asking to "Provide a script printing every possible pairs of two letters, only lower case, one by line, ordered alphabetically." Basically you should print out

```
aa
ab
a
..
ba
bb
..
zz
```

I've got the two loops going fine, but I can't remove the white space between the returned valued. So I am printing out

```
a a
```

rather than

```
aa
```

Here is my code

```
import string
x=string.ascii_lowercase

for i in x:
    for j in x:
        print(i, j).strip()
```

This question has been answered elsewhere, but I don't understand any of the answers. Thanks.

Comment: One option `print(f'{i}{j}')`

Comment: `print(i+j)` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the strings together as such

```
import string
x=string.ascii_lowercase

for i in x:
    for j in x:
        print(i+j)
```

or

```
import string
x=string.ascii_lowercase

for i in x:
    for j in x:
        print(i,j ,sep="")
```

which removed the space between the two variables and you can change it to whatever you want

Comment: In your second example you want `sep=""` instead of `end=""` otherwise it will just print everything on one line but still with a space in between

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```
import string
x=string.ascii_lowercase

for i in x:
    for j in x:
        print(i + j)
```

The output seems to match your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but it may help:

```
import string
x=string.ascii_lowercase

for i in x:
    for j in x:
        print(i+j)
```